# How can I get the pos of row dynamically ? QlikView

Tags: qlikview

I want to delete the rest of a loaded csv file based on the occurrence of a string.

```
Remove(Row, RowCnd(Interval, Pos(Top, findMeThePositionOfaGivenString('TeddyBear')),
   Pos(Bottom, 1), Select(1, 0))
```

Or just any approach to dynamically delete a range of rows!

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this during the data import stage then I would recommend

```
load yourstuff
from yourfile
where index(givenstring,'Teddybear')=0;
```

Index will return the position of the string in the larger string.
eg. index('ABC','BC')=2 so index()=0 means the string does no exist in the searched text. Be careful of the capitalisation as it will honour that, so use upper or lower to remove that kind of confusion.

I hope I understood your request.